# Cannot find module 'js-base64'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to use "js-base64": "^2.1.9" in the angular 2 app which I created using "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15", but I'm failing to import js-base64 library. I added "js-base64": "^2.1.9" to package.json in "dependencies" section:

```
package.json    
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"js-base64": "^2.1.9"
},
```

I added  "../node_modules/js-base64/base64.js" to angular-cli.json into "scripts" array.

```
angular-cli.json:

....
"scripts": ["../node_modules/js-base64/base64.js"],
....
```

and in my service file I imported the library:

```
app.service.ts

import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';
```

but the application is complaining

> /app.service.ts:6:23 
>   Cannot find module 'js-base64'.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: It may seem an idiot question, but did you do `npm install` after editing `package.json`?

Comment: Yes I did :) js-base64 is in node_modules folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `js-base64` module is pretty common, so a pre-made [Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) for that package surely exist. You can use them right away by: `npm install @types/js-base64 --save-dev`.

Then it should be OK just to use your import: `import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';` and use the module: `Base64.encode('foo')`.

Comment: In my team we incurred in this issue as well. Noticed the *@types* mentioned in this [GH issue](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/192) first. I can confirm that error went away after applying that